# Using virtual directory with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, kestrel

In ASP.NET framework 4.8 and below version the web application use IIS for processing and show data. And when we need to work with other resource like folders and network resource we can easily create Virtual Directory in IIS and map to physical path and my application work theme like normal folder.
but in Net Core we use Kestrel and IIS work as a proxy and Virtual Directory not recognized by Kestrel. I use this code but not work in function. Write this section in Configure Function

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
 FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"E:\\MyFiles"),
 RequestPath = new PathString("/PFiles"),
 EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
});
```

and this is my code :

```
var folder = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, "temp");


                var fileName = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, "temp\\test.jpeg");

                var basePath = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, "PFiles");
               
                
                var yearPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "2020");
                var monthpath = Path.Combine(basePath, "2020", "06");

                if (!Directory.Exists(yearPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(yearPath);
                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(monthpath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(monthpath);
                }

                var dpath = Path.Combine(basePath, "2020", "06");

                var destinationPath = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath, dpath);


                System.IO.File.Move(fileName, destinationPath);
```

but I receive *Access denied Error* or create directory inside of `wwwroot` folder. So, what must I do?

Comment: Show the actual error page.

Answer (score 2):

you get this error because iis default account does not have enough permission to access the folder.

you could try to assign the iis_iusrs , iusr, or  IIS AppPool<myappoolname> permission to the folder where you want to create directory.